# React - re-rendering of the component via hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How can I make a Hook state change to re-render only the render of the Hook and not the component? I went around this by adding logic to the null returning middleware component, but I don't know if it's a good idea.

```
import { useState, useMemo, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

function useTime() {
  const [a, setA] = useState(0);

  console.log("good-render", a);

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      setA(a + 1);
    }, 3000);
  }, []);
}

function Aaa() {
  useTime();

  return <></>;
}

export default function App() {
  console.log("bad-render");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Aaa />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page--please include the relevant code in the question :)

Comment: I rarely ask a question. Done ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insofar as I'm aware, you can't stop a component rendering from a hook. Whenever the state in a component changes, the component gets set to re-render, which calls all hooks in it. In fact, conditionally calling hooks would break the rules of hooks.

Your best bet would be to encapsulate all the logic you need in refs and effects if you don't want the custom hook to cause a re-render. That being said, unless you have other issues with your code (i.e. a lot of really complicated and time consuming code), then a few extra re-renders isn't the worst thing in the world.

There's definitely a point to the idea that premature optimization is a problem.

That being said, different approaches for preventing the entire tree from re-rendering would be:

1. Encapsulate the logic in a separate component without children (as you show above)
2. Use React.memo on the components that make up the children so
   React can know it should check for changes by reference on all the
   props to determine whether to re-render.